# Gin heuristic algorithm design

Tags: algorithms

(Apologies if this or an equivalent question has been asked in the past; I didn't see anything that answered this question.)

I'm designing an algorithm to compute a heuristic for a [Gin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gin_rummy) game engine. (The game I'm implementing might not be *exactly* Gin [it's a game I learned as a child] but it's extremely close.) For those unfamiliar: the game is played with a standard 52-card deck. Each player is dealt 10 cards and each turn swaps out one card with the objective of obtaining three *melds*, that is, groups of cards where each group is either all the same value (e.g. `4♠ 4♥ 4♣`) or a straight flush (e.g. `9♦ 10♦ J♦ Q♦`). (Ace is low and high but a straight may not wrap around.) The melds in a winning hand are of size 3, 3, 4.

A reasonable heuristic for the quality of a hand (I believe) is the minimum number of cards to swap out until the hand is a winning hand. This captures the intuition that e.g. `A♠ A♥ A♣` `J♠ J♥ J♦ J♣` `3♦ 4♦ 7♦` (which becomes a winning hand if the `7` becomes `2♦` or `5♦`, so has "value" 1) is better than `A♠ A♥ A♣` `J♠ J♥ J♦ J♣` `4♦ 7♦ 10♦` (with value 2) and that this is better than a random hand.

There are not very many melds in a 52-card deck so this problem is technically brute force-able. However, it lends itself to a generalization in the following way.

The deck has $s$ suits of $n$ cards each. A hand consists of $\lambda$ cards, and a winning hand has melds of size $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_g$ where $\lambda=\sum\lambda_i$ and (WLOG) $\min\{n,s\}\ge\lambda_1\ge\dots\ge\lambda_g>0$.

(So, the standard version has the values $s=4,n=13,g=3,\lambda_1=4,\lambda_2=\lambda_3=3,\lambda=10$.)

The question is: **what is the best way to compute the heuristic for the generalized version of the game?**

It's likely that the most interesting consideration is to look at asymptotics in $n$ and treat $s$ and $g$ as constants.

I'll describe below the best method I've come up with to accomplish the task, but first I'll give the tl;dr that it has asymptotic time and space requirements of $O(n^g)$ (using Dijkstra). This is the same as brute force, but it is better for asymptotic behavior in the other parameters.

**Given**: constants $s,n,g,\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_g$, and hand $h$, a vector of $\lambda$ distinct cards.

**Notation**: Denote by $M_i$ the set of length-$\lambda_i$ melds in the deck. It is clear that $\#M_i=(n+1-\lambda_i)+\binom{s-1}{\lambda_i-1}n\in O(n)$. For a given meld $m$ of size $\lambda_i$, let $m\cap h$ denote $\lambda_i$ minus the number of cards common to $m$ and $h$. The parent-set of a vertex $v$ in a $k$-ary tree is the set of $v$ and all of its parents, excluding the root $r$; formally, $P(r)=\emptyset$ and $P(v)=v\cup P(p(v))$ where $P$ is parent-set and $p(v)$ is parent.

**Data structure**: We instantiate a digraph as a $O(n)$-ary tree. Create a dummy source/root vertex as the 0th level of the graph. For each $1\le i<g$, for each vertex $v$ in level $i-1$, create one child for each meld $m$ in $M_i$ that is disjoint from each meld in $P(v)$. The weight of the edge $v\to m$ is equal to $m\cap h$.

For $i=g$, construct a level with a single copy $M_g$ and for each $v$ in level $g-1$ and $m$ in level $g$ draw edge $v\to m$ with weight $m\cap h$ is $m$ is disjoint from each meld in $P(v)$. (Note that now the graph is no longer $O(n)$-ary.)

Construct a dummy sink/destination vertex as the $(g+1)$th level of the graph and connect every vertex in level $g$ to it with weight 0.

**Computation**: Run a shortest path algorithm from source to sink. Keep track of the length of the shortest path (we don't care about the path itself).

**Analysis**: Each level for $1\le i<g$ has at most $\#M_i$ times as many vertices as the previous level; bounding $\#M_i\le cn$ for $c$ depending on $s,\lambda_i$ a constant, we conclude that level $i$ has at most $(cn)^i$ vertices with as many incoming edges (since each vertex has a unique parent). Level $g$ has only up to $cn$ vertices but may have as many as $(cn)^{g-1}\cdot\#M_g\le(cn)^g$ incoming edges, while it only has $\#M_g\le cn$ outgoing edges. Therefore $\#E\le cn+\sum\limits_{i=1}^g(cn)^i\in O(n^g)$ and $\#V\le1+cn+\sum\limits_{i=0}^{g-1}(cn)^i\in O(n^{g-1})$. With Dijkstra, the runtime becomes $O(\#E+\#V\log\#V)=O(n^g)$.